# background fade in & out on touch

Tags: android, animation, view

I'm trying to create a way of getting a views background to respond to show that it's registered the users touch, but I'd like it to look good so would like the background colour to change to a highlight colour on touch and then back out again.

So far I've created a transition animation which animates on the touched view's background :

```
animatedBackgroundView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background_touch);
animatedBackgroundView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) view.getBackground();
        transition.startTransition(500);
    }
});
```

with the background animation resource file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="#22ffffff" />
    <item android:drawable="#00ffffff" />
</transition>
```

And this works great, but if the view already has a background then that is destroyed.

Is there a way to dynamically create a similar transition animation effect without destroying the existing background?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you already fixed this ! but I was looking for the same thing and your code worked with me :) , however I added one more line to fix your problem:

```
transition.reverseTransition(500);
```